# Javascript: how to display certain amount of items from an array and display others on button click?

Tags: javascript

**Implementation:**

I have an HTML page with items container:

```
<section class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="products-title">Some title</h2>
    <div class="products-items"></div>
    <button class="products-btn">Show more</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have a data.js file with an array of items (16 items), here is an example:

```
export const products = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Product 1',
      price: 23,
      category: 'Category 1',
      imgSrc: './images/product-photo.jpg',
    },
];
```

I parsed data.js file using `.map()` to populate 'products-items' div:

```
const displayProducts = products => {
  const productsContainer = document.querySelector('.products-items');
  const newProducts = products.map(product => {
    const {
            id,
            name,
            price,
            category,
            imgSrc,
          } = product;
    return `
      <div class="product-item" data-id="${id}">
        <p>${name}</p>
        <p>${price}</p>
        <p>${category}</p>
        <img src="${imgSrc}" alt="product photo">
     </div>
    `;
  }).join('');
  productsContainer.innerHTML = newProducts;
};

export default displayProducts;
```

In app.js I've imported products variable and displayProducts function.

If I pass products variable to display products like this `displayProducts(products)`, it will show all 16 items.

**Desired result:**

What I need is to show only first 4 items and load 4 new items each time user clicks 'Show more' button. In the end all 16 items should be displayed and 'Show more' button should be hidden.

When I had all 16 items as static data in HTML. I used CSS to hide items by default: `.product-item {display: none}`

Then I added class 'product-item--active' to first 4 items to display them by default: `.product-item--active {display: block}` and used this functionality to add active class for remaining items on button click:

```
const showMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.products-btn');
let currentItems = 4;
showMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const elementList = [
        ...document.querySelectorAll('.products-items .product-item'),
    ];
    for (let i = currentItems; i < currentItems + 4; i++) {
        if (elementList[i]) {
            elementList[i].classList.add('product-item--active');
        }
    }
    currentItems += 4;

    // Hide load more button after all items were loaded
    if (currentItems >= elementList.length) {
        e.target.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

**Issue:**

But now, when items load dynamically, this functionality does not work.

I figured out how to display first 4 items using `.slice()`:

```
let firstItems = products.slice(0, 4);

displayProducts(firstItems);
```

But, I can't figure out how to load new items on button click and hide it once all item displayed.

> **Update (Solved):** I appreciate provided answers with good explanation and examples. Thank you.
> After examining them I have the following solution (in case if someone may find it useful). Also, I removed redundant
> 'product-item--active' class from CSS, now there is no need to hide items by default:

```
import { products } from './data.js';
import displayProducts from './components/displayProducts.js';

const showMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.products-btn');

let currentItems = 0;

const displayNextFour = () => {
    displayProducts(products.slice(currentItems, currentItems + 4));
    // Display next 4 items until their amount exceeds 
    // the array length 
    if (!(currentItems + 4 > products.length)) {
        currentItems += 4;
    }
    // Remove event listener from 'Show more' button and
    // hide it after all items from the array are displayed
    if (currentItems === products.length) {
        showMoreBtn.removeEventListener('click', displayNextFour);
        showMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
};

displayNextFour();

showMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', displayNextFour);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global variable to keep track of which items should be dispalyed e.g. `current_index`. Then create a function e.g. `displayNextFour()` to display four items each time and update `current_index` accordingly. Then on button click call `displayNextFour()` function.

```
let current_index = 0

const displayNextFour = () => {
  displayProducts(products.slice(current_index, current_index+4));
  //console.log(products.slice(current_index, current_index+4))
  if(current_index + 4 <= products.length)
    current_index+=4
}
```

(In `displayProducts` create elements with `product-item--active` class)

Comment: I'm interested if there are any negative consequences in using `current_index+=4` without conditional loop. In other words, should we add some condition to stop this cycle or it's OK to leave it as is (it will stop itself once no items left in the array)?

Comment: Could be. When `current_index` exceeeds the length of the data array

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV Why not `current_index + 4 <= products.length`?

Comment: @jacklearnsjs It is just preferance. But ok. Here you go

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to play with this [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using an array of 16 random strings for the content to display. It uses [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to append a block of 4 items on button click. That prevents overwriting all html on every click. The click handler is assigned using [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). If the number of items shown equals the available items, the button is disabled.

A second idea may be to hide all but [`pageSize`] items and on button click unhide the next [`pageSize`] items. See [this stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ydkcd2?file=index.js). That snippet is more generic: it enables a variable amount of items and setting a page size (number of items to show subsequently). It requires no extra variables for tracking.

```js
initRandomStrExt();

document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
const fakeArray = [...Array(16)].map(v => String.getRandom(32));

// show first 4 items on page load
addFourItems(fakeArray);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`products-btn`)) {
    return addFourItems(fakeArray);
  }
}

function addFourItems(fromArr) {
  // determine n of currently visible items
  const start = document.querySelectorAll(`.product-item`).length;
  
  // disable the button if all items will be visible after running this
  if (start === fromArr.length - 4) {
    document.querySelector(`.products-btn`).setAttribute(`disabled`, true);
  }
  
  // append 4 items of the array to the .product-items container
  document.querySelector(`.products-items`)
    .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,
      `<div>${fromArr.slice(start, start + 4)
      //                    ^ slice the next 4 items from the array
        .map((item, i) => `<div class="product-item">${i + 1 + start} - ${
          item}</div>`).join(``)}</div>`);
}

// for demo, random string helper
function initRandomStrExt() {
  if (String.getRandom) {
    return;
  }
  const characters = [...Array(26)]
    .map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 65))
    .concat([...Array(26)].map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)))
    .concat([...Array(10)].map((x, i) => `${i}`));
  const getCharacters = excludes =>
    excludes && characters.filter(c => !~excludes.indexOf(c)) || characters;

  String.getRandom = (len = 12, excludes = []) => {
    const chars = getCharacters(excludes);
    return [...Array(len)]
      .map(() => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
      .join("");
  };
};
```

```html
<section class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="products-title">Some title</h2>
    <div class="products-items"></div>
    <p><button class="products-btn">Show more</button></p>
  </div>
```